# how to create a pair rdd with an int key

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

i am new to spark, i want to create a JavaPairRDD  to be able to sort it and compare between keys, as it shows the sample of code bellow, i tried to create a JavaPairRDD  but after using the function sortByKey(), i noticed that it treats keys as Strings not as integers.

```
   JavaRDD<String> csvFileC = sc.textFile(currentFile);
   JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> pairsC = csvFileC.mapToPair(new keyData()).sortByKey(true).cache();
```

for example if pairsC contains the following elements :

> (1,as),(2,you),(12,er),(3,cu),(22,hh)

so after using sortByKey() and display it again i find it like:

> (1,as),(12,er),(2,you),(22,hh),(3,cu)

which means it treats keys as Strings not as integers, but the result which i look for is as follows:

> ( 1,as),(2,you),(3,cu),(12,er),(22,hh)

so how can i deal with my keys as int?
for more details, this is the function keyData that i use to transform the RDD to a PairRDD

```
    public static class keyData implements PairFunction <String, Integer,   String> 
     {
     public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String x) {
     String[] strs = x.split(",");
        return new Tuple2(strs[0], x.replaceFirst(strs[0]+",", ""));
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code even work? The return type of the `call` is `Tuple2<Integer, String>` but when your create the new `Tuple2`it is of type `Tuple2<String, String>`. To fix this issue you can simple convert your String to Integer:

```java
return new Tuple2(Integer.parseInt(strs[0]), x.replaceFirst(strs[0]+",", ""));
```

Furthermore make sure you only have integers in your first split element. Typically a header of the file has to be removed or skipped if present to avoid `NumberFormatExceptions`.

However, give a comparator to `sortByKey` see the [JavaDocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#sortByKey(java.util.Comparator,%20boolean)) for more information. This will result in something like:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> parisC =
csvFileC.sortByKey(Comparator.comparing(tuple2 -> tuple2._1, true);
```

Comment: isn't it possible to modify call to make it to  return a tuple2<Integer,String>? if yes than how to do it? because i need keys as integers

Comment: Yes it is, I extended my answer a bit.

Comment: and maybe it s illogical but yup my code works normally

Comment: Does it work now @asmaspark ? After adding the comparator?

Comment: i think the problem is in keyData function because i get a NumberFormatException

Comment: i found the reason of NumberFormatException , i didn't subtract the header "id,........" now it works but without the comparator

Comment: i am just wondering why it doesn't recognize the function comparing that you used???

Comment: in some cases the IDE scala support is poor and "._1" is not recognized. To use the code above you need at least java 7

Comment: i musing java not scala to write the code and i am using jdk 8

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that i used:

```
        String headerSTR = "Id,Name,Color,Age";
       JavaRDD<String> header = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(headerSTR));


        String currentFile = "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/source.csv";          

        JavaRDD<String> csvFileC = c.textFile(currentFile).subtract(header);  

      JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> pairsC = csvFileC.mapToPair(new keyData()).sortByKey(true).cache();
```

and i modified the keyData function exactly like @Matthias Kricke recommended